# combination Key

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table that have one primary key, and now i want add to this table another primary key, actually i want  have two primary keys and i don't know how:(
i know it's a simple and silly question but I will be grateful if any one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "second primary key". The word "primary" shows this clearly...

You can add several **unique** keys (which can behave like a primary key) or you can define a primary key consisting of several columns.

Hope this helps...